# how to embed for statement in openx template (template.html)

Tags: php, html, openx

Now i'm writing a openx plugin.
But now i have an array data that got from database.
when i used statement foreach embedding into html page (a template in openx) i write:

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td>Action</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    {foreach key=id item=row from=$rsResult}
    <tr>
        <td>{$row.id}</td>
        <td>{$row.name}</td>
        <td>{$row.description}</td>
        <td><a href="/www/admin/plugins/demoHelloWorld/demoHelloWorld-delete.php?id={$row.id}">DELETE</a></td>
    </tr>
    {/foreach}
    </table>
```

but i don't know embed for statement into html page (openx template).
can u help me?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I found resolving this problem:
i used smarty tags.
in php:

```
for ($i=1;$i++;$i<10) {
 echo $i;
}
```

with smarty tags:

```
{section name=temp loop=9}
 {$smarty.section.foo.iteration}
{/section}
```

this's my research sesult. :)